# is there a way to reload data into XtraGrid GridView without losing its visual state like filters, group row opens etc?

Tags: gridview, devexpress, xtragrid

if I want to both change the database and render the change on the GridView, at present I am forced to change CType(grd.DataSource, DataView).Table cell values explicitly because I don't want to lose the GridView's state like which columns are grouped, which group rows are open, which columns are filtered etc. The changes involved are not structurally significant (they don't even change number of rows) although I think that even rendering changes that do change that would not have been impossible.

Anyway, so does XtraGrid provide me with a generic way to reload the data into GridView while preserving all this GridView state? Or do I basically need to write my own generic code for this purpose if I really want it, or else stick to the changing GridView values in place without reload for the particular cases I am dealing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awhile ago I have written this code and it is published in the DevExpress site at:

[How to preserve the XtraGrid View state](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E776)

[How to preserve the XtraGrid view state in multi level master/detail](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E1466)